# citus: Can I add one more replica for a distributed table

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, citus

I have a distributed table,but this table only has one replica,only one replica doesn't have
ha, I want and one more replica for the table,can i? how to do?

I have search online help docs,but didn't find any solution.

Comment: If you want to add another worker node, you could do so by using `citus_add_node`, [see] (https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.1/admin_guide/cluster_management.html#add-a-worker). But if you want to add replication node, then Citus uses the standard Postgresql [streaming replication](https://docs.citusdata.com/en/v11.1/faq/faq.html#how-does-citus-handle-failure-of-a-worker-node)

Answer (score 1):

Replica's in Citus are *not* an HA solution. For HA you will need to setup any postgres tooling for every member in your cluster to stream WAL to another node. Citus specializes in distributed queries and separates that problem from HA by relying on proven technology available in the postgres ecosystem.

If you want to scale out reads adding a replica can help. However adding replica's have a significantly high impact on write throughput. Before adding replica's please thoroughly test that your database can handle your expected load. And yet again, if HA is your goal, don't add Citus replica's instead, apply postgres HA solutions to every worker and coordinator.

Increasing the replica count of an already distributed table is due to above reasoning not an operation Citus provides out of the box. Easiest would be to create a new table and use an INSERT INTO SELECT clause to reinsert the data into a table with appropriate shard_count and replica's according to your application needs.